# Updating Linked Table while the Table is open

Tags: ms-access

I have a front end MS Access Database that allows users to display records. This is based on a central .txt file that I have stored on a network drive. Each morning, I perform an ETL process that takes data from a variety of sources, combines it, and stores it in the .txt file. If someone is using the database and has one of the queries open that references this .txt file, I get an error that says the file is currently in use and I cannot make a change to it.

I've attempted writing a query that pulls the data from the .txt file and stores it in a table within the Access database so that it is not actively referencing the base file, but if multiple people attempt to run this query they get errors because you cannot replace a table that is open by someone else.

Does anyone have any experience in getting around an update issue like this? Would I be better off choosing a different front end other than Access to display queried records from a central table?

Comment: What do you mean by 'replace table'? What kind of query are you running? Have 'temp' table in frontend so each user has their own copy. Replace records, not table.

Comment: By replace table I mean that I fully replace the .txt file that contains the data. I basically run through my ETL and save this new file in the same location for reference by the Access database. The query I run basically filters this main file by certain region or customer number. A user in the Access DB selects the region they want and it displays a list of records.

Comment: Okay, my comment still applies. This assumes each user runs their own copy of frontend installed on their machine.